# Internal Server Error when implementing Allauth with Django, Nginx and uWSGI to Production Server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

As of this moment, I have been able to successfully implement google sign into my website while I run it locally on my machine while using a plugin known as Django-allauth. However, when I try moving it over to my AWS lightsail server, I get an “internal server error” the moment the website is attempted to load.

To give some information to how we are running the website, I have the backend running through Django, and the frontend which serves the static files running through NGINX. The front end is connected through uWSGI and micro uWSGI to the backend. Also, I have all of this automized through emperor so that I don’t have to constantly run the command to run the server. On my local machine, the server is running only with Django.

While doing troubleshooting by entering one line of code at a time for the integration of allauth, I discovered that the error pops up when I try adding “allauth” to installed apps in the settings.py file. Thinking that this was because allauth may not have been installed, I tried installing it again in different versions to see if that would make a difference. It did not.

Through the research that I have done, I have found that it is not uncommon for internal server errors to occur when moving from a testing to a production server, but have not been able to find anything that is specific to our error. I have tried implementing some of the fixes that I have found with no success. My next thought was that it had something to do with the fact that we are using NGINX and Django, and tried to see if allauth was incompatible with NGINX. However, the research I have done has shown nothing alluding to the fact that it is incompatible. Also, I tried looking through the NGINX error logs and nothing seems to be out of sorts.

Does anyone know why this internal server error might occur? Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that on your server, you have debug set to false, try switching to true, or check your log files, also try as Django admin email messages to see what causes the error. Maybe you didn't run migration???

Comment: Hi Martins, yes, I do have debug set to false as a security measure. Even when I try turning it on and have the error, all it shows is an internal server error. In terms of the migration, I try running it but all it says is that there are no changes and no migrations are made.

Comment: Are you using environment variable? I have had such problems before only to realise that a package wasn't installed after I made some modifications to my project. If debug message is showing server error, means env is still active. Check your logs.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS or use this to receive the error message via email. Note you have to setup email backend.

Comment: Sorry, this may seem like a really stupid question, but how do i access the logs?

Comment: Also, when I say it shows an internal server error, this is shown when I search the website. There is no debug message. Yes, I am using an virtual env

Comment: add ADMINS = [('your_name', 'your_email'),] in your settings.py file to get the full error on your email